# Draggable Textboxes do not work in IE9 as a base?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I was looking at other questions and it wasn't really giving me answers i was looking for.  My question is this:  I am running IE9, pure.  I have a VM that has it, so it isnt accidentally using a modern JS Engine.

I was trying to turn on draggable by saying:

```
$("input:text").draggable();//with jQuery UI 1.9.2
```

but it doesnt seem to do it.  My thought is that there is some sort of stop propigation on the  mousedown/focus of the input which prevents draggable from working.

Here is a fiddle that i tested with:  Win7:IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/J5qS9/
I noticed it also doesnt work with Chrome.edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a option called: *cancel*

This tells what it doesnt affect.  Here are the defaults

> Default: "input,textarea,button,select,option"

by http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel

If you say:

```
$("input").draggable({cancel:null})
// or
$("input").draggable({cancel: "textarea,button,select,option"});
```

it will allow you to drag on everything or inputs (while maintaining other rules) respectivally.